# Not enough boot space to download Ubuntu 14.04.03

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

Hi this is slightly different to the other problems listed under this heading - brand new 1TB drive so no old kernals.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            3.9G  808M  3.1G  21% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           789M  1.4M  788M   1% /run
/dev/sr0       1006M 1006M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      963M  963M     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G  1.3M  3.9G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            3.9G   39M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
```

I am running Trusty Tahr from a CD but when I try to load I get:

`X  has at least 6.6GB available drive space` i.e. I don't.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-25-generic

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic                         3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic                   3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid                         3.19.0.25.12                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

done `sudo apt-get clean` just for giggles - no effect.

I assume I have to do something with partitions but I am a little green at dealing with them and some of the posts on here have assisted in confusion as to whether or not I actually need to do anything.

```
Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  258MB   256MB   ext2               msftdata
 3      258MB   3001GB  3000GB                     lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 2983GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2983GB  2983GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 17.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  17.1GB  17.1GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your commands are showing the flash drive, not your hard drive. You must have partitions, but it makes a difference if your system is UEFI or BIOS and if later you are also installing Windows. If you just want one very large / (root) partition on hard drive, you can use the auto install option. http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu Or more advanced manual partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Could you add `sudo parted --list&&lsblkid` after reporting back to suggestions from @oldfred?

Comment: I did look at the old fred stuff but I am not getting any of the interactive screens that he lists so I was a little confused

Comment: If you run your system from CD, how can it "load" anything. The system is run from read-only media.

Comment: In order to create a UEFI file system, you need to have a partition of at least 25 MB called /boot/efi.  I ran into that.  I had one, but since I was upgrading anyway, I did the upgrade.  

It seems that if you are creating a partition table for 14.04 and booting UEFI, you need a /boot and a /boot/efi partition.  Each about 25-50 MB

My partitions are as follows: /boot/efi - 380 MiB/4.11 used; / 23.84 GiB 12.5 used; and linux-swap and /home were the rest of the drive.

Comment: I have a bootable CD that is created to be downloadable - this is fairly normal.  When I start to run it I get the first screen on the old fred post BUT I am told there is not enough disc space and the installation process stalls and does not allow me to proceed. In order to investigate what to do next I am running the system off the disc as an alternative not a solution. I do not get any option to create a partition, auto or otherwise. I am going to manually 'part' the disc. Going in now - wish me luck. If you don't hear back, tell my dog I didn't really mean what I said about it's ears.

Answer (score 0):

You run the system from LiveCD. It is not installed.

That is the reason why you cannot "load" anything.

Comment: Wrong way round - I am running the system from the CD because I can not load it

Comment: Hi - thanks for the advice but I tracked the problem down to a very odd intermittent. Individually the HDD, the SATA cable and the power cable all worked fine but the combination of the three - for some reason - did not work. I sourced a new HDD and all is well. As an odd postscript the other HDD is now happily chugging away in another build I completed a while back!  The trials and tribulations of building tech, heh!